# Getting Toolbar in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I set up a toolbar in my main activity and when I go inside a fragment, I want to add a slider on it. If I had had the access to the Toolbar object, I would simply do:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


Spinner mNavigationSpinner = new SpinnerTrigger(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
toolbar.addView(mNavigationSpinner);
```

But if I get it using

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
```

I don't have any `addView()` method. So my question is, how can I add a view to the Toolbar in fragment if the Toolbar itself was created in an Activity.

I'm not sure if this is the best view of going about this, but I don't think I can have the Spinner in defined in the layout, because most of my fragments don't use it, they simply set a title to the toolbar. But at the same time, it would be great if I could define the toolbar once in the main activity and not redo it for every fragment.

Comment: when you are creating a fragment object, you can pass the toolbar object to fragment constructor. This is what i have done ..

Comment: @Moinkhan how? What object should I pass to fragment?

Comment: @Talha when you are creating fragment from activity  like Fragment fm = YourFragment.getInstance(yourToolbarinstance)... but i think accepted answer is good way to achive this ..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Another way of achieving the same thing from Ellitz answer, inside the fragment access the toolbar (or any other view inside activity) directly:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can get it using

```
Toolbar refTool = ((NameOfClass)getActivity()).toolbar;
```

or, create an instance of your MainActivity, then, override `onAttach(Activity activity)` and assign your instance object of MainActivity to the activity in onAttach()

Comment: If there is no built in methods for this, I guess this would be the best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See toolbar main purpose is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html read here so there are nothing deference in toolbar and actionbar. so if you want to add view to toolbar before it set to Actionbar then `toolbar.addView(your view);` is fine but after apply apply to `setactionbar(toolbar)` or `setSupportActionbar(toolbar)` you can set view to actionbar.

ex.  ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setView(Your view)

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a casting to what `Budius` said.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

is the right way of doing it. Because

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

returns a view. This will give you error and you should cast it to `Toolbar`.